# Using matplotlib to "smoothen" a line with very few points

Tags: python, matplotlib

It caught me off-guard how there seems to be no default support for doing something like, nor even any straightforward way.

This kind of operation is usually as simple as clicking a button in a program like Excel.

```
import random 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [random.randint(0,10) for _ in range(4)]

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

[image: img]

Basically, for the above graph with only 4 points, I'm wondering what the least complex way is to simply smoothen the line so it resembles a curve instead.

Update:
So using a cubic spline mostly does a great job!:

[image: img]

One issue, though. In the curve, we see that based on how the curve is built, there are points higher than the actual maximum point observed, and points lower than the actual minimum. Is there a workaround to make it so the curve does not exceed the maximum observed and minimum points?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple solution uses scipy's [interp1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#d-interpolation-interp1d) to create a cubic spline through the points.

An approach to avoid that the curve goes outside the range of the surrounding points, is to create a cubic Bézier curve with extra in-between points added.

Another approach involves scipy's monotonic cubic interpolation, [`PchipInterpolator`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.PchipInterpolator.html), a.k.a. `pchip`. This function *preserves monotonicity in the interpolation data and does not overshoot if the data is not smooth.*

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.path import Path
import matplotlib.patches as patches
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d, pchip

x = np.array([1, 3, 4, 5, 6])
y = np.array([1, 6, 2, 5, 9])

plt.plot(x, y, 'ob:', lw=1)

x_smooth = np.linspace(x[0], x[-1], 500)
f1 = interp1d(x, y, kind='cubic')

plt.plot(x_smooth, f1(x_smooth), 'g')

f2 = pchip(x, y)
plt.plot(x_smooth, f2(x_smooth), 'r', lw=2)

x3 = np.convolve(np.repeat(x, 3), [1/3, 1/3, 1/3])[2:-2]
y3 = np.repeat(y, 3)[1:-1]
f3 = interp1d(x3, y3, kind='cubic')

plt.plot(x3, y3, 'k--', lw=0.5)

verts = list(zip(x3, y3))
codes = [Path.MOVETO] + [Path.CURVE4 for _ in range(len(verts) - 1)]
patch = patches.PathPatch(Path(verts, codes), facecolor='none', lw=3, edgecolor='m')
plt.gca().add_patch(patch)

plt.legend(['Linear', 'Cubic Spline', 'pchip', 'extra points', 'adapted Bezier'], handleheight=0.1)

plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Note that also multiple other types of [spline functions](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/interpolate.html#spline-interpolation) are available.

Comment: Hi, that does work very beautifully! https://i.gyazo.com/c91b52d5fc7268cb09b2ba655f588db2.png . Just one question, however. In the curve, we see that based on how the curve is built, there are points higher than the actual maximum point observed, and points lower than the actual minimum. Is there a workaround to make it so the curve does not exceed the maximum observed and minimum points?

Comment: @Yeahprettymuch Well, I do not see orange points higher or lower than the maximum and minimum of the blue points… could you please be more specific because I don't understand your issue?

Comment: Hi gboff. What I mean is, if we look at the 4 points the curve was made from, we realize there are parts of the curve where it goes above and below the maximum/minimum value that was observed among these 4 points. What I'm trying to do is to prevent this and respect the given max/min values.

Comment: Is this adapted bezier what you were looking for?

Comment: Wow, I wouldn't have guessed that was the word for it. Thanks a lot, that looks perfect!!

Comment: Hi again if you're still around @JohanC ! So I just realized that the adapted bezier really only works if all the data points on the x-axis are spaced out the same, however if the graph is something like this, it no longer works: https://i.gyazo.com/d2ac5cece53c3c1e2e66aeb4a1318a0f.png . Seems like the fix to this has to do with altering the bit of the code where linspace is used - but I'm not quite sure what the right adaptation should be.

Comment: Hi JohanC, again thank you so so much. this is off-topic but may I ask what your background education/proficiencies are in? it's frustrating that i would not even have known where to start looking in order to figure this out. wondering the specific kind of background that would be suited to this, since this seems second nature to someone like you.

Comment: Well, I studied computer science with a strong interest in everything graphics related.

Comment: Hi again @JohanC!! Little bit of a follow-up question if you can be bothered. What i'm trying to fix is the first 4 points here: https://i.gyazo.com/62a8481fca5acc518a0b2ad6976586c6.png . The adapted bezier works ridiculously well, however it's detracting from the aesthetics just slightly. the change I have in mind is for it to consider all sequence of points where there is a continual decrease/increase as a single 'bezier'! It's just a little hard to see how this would be fit into the code given above. Wondering if you could point in the right direction.

Comment: This graph would have been better to include @JohanC: https://i.gyazo.com/dd3d531c5dde9991a61e471909a6909f.png. The yellow line represents the "smoother" curve that looks like it would be a better visual fit.

Comment: I just added `pchip` which doesn't have the flattening problem of the bezier approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [LOESS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_regression) or the [Nadarya-Watson estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_regression#Nadaraya%E2%80%93Watson_kernel_regression) (and variants) to obtain a smooth curve from discrete data.  These methods perform an "moving average" sort of technique, so that they will *generally* not produce points outside of the range of the original data (for `x` values that are within the domain of the original data).

There is a [convenient python library](https://github.com/csbrown/pylomo) (full disclaimer, I am the author of the library) that makes such models easy to build.  Take care that the result will generally not pass through the given data points.

As the bandwidth parameter goes to 0, the curve will become the linear interpolant.  As it goes to infinity, the curve will become a single ordinary least squares regression line.  Bandwidths between those two values produce a continuous sequence of curves between those two extremes.

```
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sklearn.linear_model
import local_models.local_models as pylomo

np.random.seed(1)
x = [1, 2, 3, 4]
y = [random.randint(0,10) for _ in range(4)]
x_test = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 100)

kernel = pylomo.GaussianKernel(bandwidth=0.5)
LOESS = pylomo.LocalModels(sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression(), kernel=kernel)
LOESS.fit(np.array(x).reshape(-1,1), np.array(y))
y_pred = LOESS.predict(x_test.reshape(-1,1))

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(x_test, y_pred, c='r')
plt.show()
```

[image]