# Force fit a spline on given extrema points

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

I have a set of points, which when connected by straight lines looks as shown below:
[image: Linear Fit]

As seen in the linear fit, the points to which the curves are fit, are meant to be extremas in the curve, that is, local maxima and minima.

**I want to fit a spline or a smooth curve through these points such that these points still remain the local maxima/minima.**
I was using python, but any algorithm to do the above in any language or even plain maths is appreciated.

---

I tried using `InterpolatedUnivariateSpline` from `scipy.interpolate`, and the results for degree 2 and 3 are showing below:

[image: Order 2 Fit]

[image: Order 3 Fit]

Order 2 curve comes close to the desired result, but is there a way I can impose the condition that these points remain the extrema?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62662170/python-generate-polynomial-from-turning-point-coordinates/62663078#62663078

Comment: Hi Warren, thanks for that! That's almost exactly what I wanted. I was excited to learn about this new function. Although, it had an issue of making the derivatives for the end points also `0` which I didn't want. @ev-br's answer below, which also uses the same Hermite method takes care of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this data as shown, PchpInterpolator would probably do.

The reason is that the algorithm forces a zero slope at the data point if the linear slopes to the left and to the right have different signs.

Demo:

```
>>> from scipy.interpolate import pchip
>>> xx = np.arange(9)
>>> yy = np.cos(xx*2*np.pi/8) + 0.4*(-1)**(xx)
>>> pch = pchip(xx, yy)
>>> pch(xx, nu=1)   # derivative at data points

array([-1.68578644,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,
        0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  1.68578644])
```

Comment: Thanks @ev-br. This is exactly what I was looking for. The Pchip method leaves the end points alone, unlike CubicHermiteSpline.

Comment: I had a couple of questions. If I am not wrong the Pchip methods fits cubic curves. Is there any method to fit a quadratic curve instead of cubic one with similar constraints on the slopes?
My second question is what exactly is the `nu` parameter? I couldn't get it properly from the documentation, yet.

Comment: also, your solution is missing the declaration of the `xx` variable. It would be great if you could make the solution more whole by adding that. Thanks!

Comment: Edited in the definition of `xx`. `nu` is the derivative (c.f. the docs for the `__call__` method). Yes, the C in `pchip` is for Cubic. Piecewise quadratic interpolants: there's nothing ready-made in scipy.interpolate. Even-order splines are usually worse, but nothing prevents you from trying to cook up your own interpolator and representing it as a `PPoly` or `BPoly` instance. The latter might be more convenient, because you can explicitly provide the derivatives via `BPoly.from_derivatives` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Given your constraints, you will need to function fit, not curve fit.

so you need a polynomial with constraints

```
P(xi) = yi 
P'(xi) = 0
```